# Problemas com if no managedbean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Possuo um formulário de login com os campos matricula e senha. Estou tentando validar esse login onde apenas a matricula "92018" possa logar no sistema, mas quando o método logar é chamado, ele não passa pelo if, mesmo tendo digitado o valor correto, já coloquei um breakpoint para ver se o valor estaria diferente, mas não está. O que poderia ser?

ManagedBean

```
public String Logar()
    {
            if(associado.getMatricula()=="92018")
            {
                return "/Teste";    
            }

        return"/sucesso";   
    }
```

Formulário de login

```
<h:form id="formLogin">
            <p:fieldset legend="Insira os dados de acesso"
                style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <p:outputLabel for="matricula" value="Matricula: " />
                <br />
                <p:inputText id="matricula" value="#{LoginBean.associado.matricula}"
                    required="true" autocomplete="off" />
                <br />
                <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha: " />
                <br />
                <p:inputText id="senha" value="#{LoginBean.associado.senha}"
                    required="true" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <p:commandButton value="Entrar" id="logar"
                    action="#{LoginBean.Logar}" ajax="false" />
                <br />
            </p:fieldset>
        </h:form>
```

Classe

```
public class Associado {

    private String matricula,senha;

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não compare strings com == em Java, isso irá comparar o endereço dos objetos contendo suas palavras, ao invés de comparar as palavras em si.
Para comparar strings utilize o método equals, dessa maneira:

```
String palavra = "StackOverflow";

if (palavra.equals("StackOverflow")) {
    //são iguais
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado! Comecei a estudar java ontem e não sabia deste detalhe.